# Does Wowza rtsp server support basic authentication?

Tags: rtsp, wowza, rtsp-client

I'm creating a demo app for streaming video from android devices to Wowza server. When I try to connect to authenticate `RTSP` client, the Wowza server seems to ignore it. Here are my `RTSP` request and response from server.

```
OPTIONS rtsp://my_rtsp_server_address:1935/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz47==

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1 build17882
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
```

Actually my username and password are `admin:1234`, after encoded with Base64 it became `YWRtaW46MTIzNA==`, but when I tried to replace with **wrong value**, the Wowza server did not take care about it and still return success code.

My question is does Wowza server support basic authentication or digest authentication. I read on https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt about rtsp authorization, but it does not exist anymore.

Thank you for your supporting!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link:
[Wowza RTSP stream authentication](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?15446-Wowza-RTSP-stream-authentication)